# How to create a preloader for images in a carousel

Tags: jquery, css, preloader, image-preloader

I am looking for a way to preload images for my website carousel. They are ugly loaded at the the page load.
Is there a modern elegant way to do it?

I tried without success:

```
  var images = [];
  $('.gallery_panel').each(function(){images.push($(this).attr('src'));});
  $('.gallery_thumbs').each(function(){images.push($(this).attr('src'));});
```

and a css preload:

```
<style>
   #preloadedImages {
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     display: inline;
     background-image: url(images/....png);
     background-image: url(images/....png);
     background-image: url(images/....png);
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was a good start. Basically do something like this:

```
var images = [];

$('.gallery_panel').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = src;
    images.push(image);
});
$('.gallery_thumbs').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = src;
    images.push(image);
});
```

Comment: I wonder why did you declared images as an array. I think you meant  var images = {}

Comment: I also I don't understand why you instantiate the object at every loop. Why not queieng them in one object?

Comment: You have to create an image object for each image you want to preload, and I'm just pushing them onto an array for storage.

Comment: Oh then is an array of objects?

Comment: Yes an array of images. Creating the `Image`, setting its source should preload it, then I just dump it into an array.